# Regex find string variable

Tags: c#, regex

How can I find something like `fo32p_dasf[0] = (string)"random string here";` with Regex.Match? I have problem using (string) within the regex string.

Comment: Just use [Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx). Regex is massive overkill for this type of procedure.

Comment: I'm confused... are you casting that string literal as a string? If so, why?

Comment: Here's your regex:  `/fo32p_dasf\[0\] = \(string\)"random string here";/`

Comment: @user3244451 Well... it's bound to happen if your question isn't very clear...

Answer (score 0):

Because parentheses have special meaning in Regex, you need to **escape** them with a backslash.

However, backslashes also have meaning in C# strings, so you need to escape the escape.

Square brackets also have a special meaning in regex, so they need escaping, and the quotes need escaping, so after all that, you end up with something like this:

```
var pattern = "fo32p_dasf\\[0\\] = \\(string\\)\".*\";";
```